# Circe: decoding Json field with alias, how to do it?

Tags: json, scala, deserialization, circe

Assuming that I have a Scala case class that contains a field "someRandomName" that has an alias "someArbitraryName":

```
case class NN(
  name1: Option[String],
  @alias("someArbitraryName") someRandomName: String
 // ... 100 more optional fields
)
```

I need to derive a decoder semi-automatically that can parse both:

```
{"someRandomName" : "abc"}
```

and

```
{"someArbitraryName" : "abc"}
```

into the exact same instance of the class `NN`

What's the shortest way to do it in circe?